# What's the best way to migrate a tag from StackOverflow to ServerFault?

Tags: support, tags

I'm asking a new question related to [tidal-scheduler] in ServerFault but the tag doesn't exist here yet. The tag exists in StackOverflow but the question doesn't fit there. I would like to migrate the tag from SO to SF. It's that possible?

In case that's possible how do I do it?

NOTE:
I tried to create the tag in SF from the info in SO but I don't have enough rep yet to do that and IMHO that's not the best way to do it: If we can migrate questions se should be able to migrate tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't migrate tags at all and you can't create them here without enough rep points (300 are required). Just create a question with appropriate other tags and leave a comment or flag asking to create this new tag.

Before doing so, make extra sure the question you post is [on-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Thanks! I'll leave a comment asking to create the  [tidal-scheduler] tag.